# How to add statically-assigned subnet to Cisco 887VAW router?

Tags: cisco, router, subnet

As an IOS neophyte, I've been struggling to configure our office's new Cisco 887VAW ADSL router. After much head-scratching I've managed to sort the ADSL end out, and configured the router to provide DHCP on its ethernet interface (192.16.10.0/24, with the router on 192.168.10.1, NATing to the ISP-supplied IP address).

Now I need to configure the router to forward traffic for the /29 subnet we've got from our ISP. The previous router was configured with a second IP address (from the /29) which is specified as the outbound gateway for our various servers; how do I replicate this on the Cisco, and tell it how to route inbound data for those addresses?

Comment: You should be able to configure the /29 exactly the same as your /24 if they're sharing the same Layer 2 (switches etc) network inside your network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running a flat network internally (no vlans on the 4 LAN ports) you can just add the ISP assigned address as a secondary:

```
int vlan 1
ip address x.x.x.x 255.255.255.248 secondary
```

If you are running vlans internally you need to define a new vlan, add the address to that interface and assign LAN ports to that vlan:

```
vlan 2
 name ISP_Assigned

int vlan 2
 description ISP Assigned Space
 ip add x.x.x.x 255.255.255.248
 no shut

int fa0/x
 description Switchport Assigned to ISP IP Space
 switchport access vlan 2
 no shut
```

Comment: `secondary` was the keyword I was missing, thanks :)